# When to Use Bound and When to use Frame

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, frame, bounds

I have found out that

The bounds of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The frame of an UIView is the rectangle, expressed as a location (x,y) and size (width,height) relative to the superview it is contained within.

But my doubt is in which scenario I will have the bounds  to be used . Cant we use frames in

all the cases ? Is there a need to use the bound ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5):

- The **frame** property contains the frame rectangle, which specifies the size and location of the view in its superview’s coordinate system.
- The **bounds** property contains the bounds rectangle, which specifies the size of the view (and its content origin) in the view’s own local coordinate system.

Frame:

> You use the center and frame properties primarily for manipulating the
>   geometry of the current view. For example, you use these properties
>   when building your view hierarchy or changing the position or size of
>   a view at runtime. If you are changing only the position of the view
>   (and not its size), the center property is the preferred way to do so.
>   The value in the center property is always valid, even if scaling or
>   rotation factors have been added to the view’s transform. The same is
>   not true for the value in the frame property, which is considered
>   invalid if the view’s transform is not equal to the identity
>   transform.

Bounds:

> **You use the bounds property primarily during drawing**. The bounds
>   rectangle is expressed in the view’s own local coordinate system. The
>   default origin of this rectangle is (0, 0) and its size matches the
>   size of the frame rectangle. Anything you draw inside this rectangle
>   is part of the view’s visible content. If you change the origin of the
>   bounds rectangle, anything you draw inside the new rectangle becomes
>   part of the view’s visible content.

So you do the following things with the **frame**:

- resizing view
- moving / reposition view

Situation when you should use **bounds**:

- when you do drawing inside the view with bounds e.g. in the `drawRect:` method of `UIView`.
- adding subViews to a parent views bounds

Comment: The bound is still confusing me . Is there any coding example ?